# Check if the thread is waiting-java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to check whether the thread is in 'wait state' inside an if loop. I find `Thread.getState()` which returns `NEW, RUNNABLE, BLOCKED, WAITING, TIMED_WAITING or TERMINATED`. But i am confused how it can be used in a loop because i do not know what value it returns. `if (Thread.getState()==??)` what should come in place of ??. is it string `'WAIT'`.

Comment: It's Enum. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Comment: *"I want to check whether the thread is in 'wait state' inside an if loop."* - Polling the state of something in a loop is probably a BAD IDEA.

Comment: Thank you but i am able to catch IllegalMonitorStateException so do not need this. i should have changed my question because i do not know my thread is in wait state or not. Now i do not have to bother about that.